# Can't set margin from the edge

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I followed Apple website's guide for Swift
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1

After I placed the 3 objects on the drawing board and stacked them, it aligned with the left margin nicely but after I set the constraints for adaptive interface, it aligns with the very edge of the screen. Any help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdtXM.png

Answer (score 0):

> but after I set the constraints for adaptive interface, it aligns with the very edge of the screen. Any help?

You just haven't configured the constraints properly. It's hard to say exactly what you've done wrong without seeing how your constraints are set up, but I can give an example of what they should look like. Here's a button in a view, constrained so that the button is inset 20 pixels from the top and leading edges of the view. With the button selected in Interface Builder, we can see the constraints:

[image: constraints in interface builder]

And looking at the constraints in the Size inspector:

[image: constraints shown in Size inspector]

(The button looks a little different from what you might expect because this happens to be a macOS project, but the constraints work exactly the same way as they do in iOS.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I set the left margin to 0 and ticked "Constraint to margins" when setting the constraint. It still aligns to the left edge and not to the margin. Turned out that the cause is Safe Area and when I disabled it, it now aligns to the margin. Thanks for your help though :)